# Flat file reset column

Tags: ssis

what exactly the reset column does in flat file connecion manager editor of flat file source ,DF of an SSIS package
Is it equivalent to refresh the metadata.

[image]

Comment: What "reset column" are you talking about?   Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: You should click the button to find out. The best way to learn is by doing. :|

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Silly question and silly answer :)

Remove all columns

more detail msdn link below

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180239.aspx